# How to have file written automatically in the startup folder when a new user signs up/in on JuPyter hub?

Tags: python, kubernetes, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am using JuPyter hub on k8s. It has a persistent volume claim. I want to have my users use a variable `run_id = "sample"`every time they use jupyter notebook.

Doing so requires making a file `aviral.py` in the path `/home/jovyan/.ipython/profile_default/startup` with the content `run_id = "sample"`.

I have to do this manually and would want this to be done as soon as the new user's pod is created for the first time i.e. the file gets written there itself.

Is there any way to automate this?

Everything mentioned here is taken off the shelf, as described here:

https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup-jupyterhub.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to create a [`ConfigMap`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) from your `aviral.py` file:

`kubectl create configmap aviral-configmap --from-file=aviral.py`

And add it to the `Deployment` used by JuPyter Hub.
You can read how to [Customizing your Deployment](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending-jupyterhub.html) as this would require modification of you `config.yaml` and applying the changes.

Inside your deployment you need to add following container spec:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: <Container_Name>
      image: <Image_Name>
      volumeMounts:
        - name: my-config
          mountPath: /home/jovyan/.ipython/profile_default/startup
  volumes:
    - name: my-config
      configMap:
        name: aviral-configmap
```

If I'm not mistaken and this is indeed correct [config.yaml](https://jupyernetes.com/config-yaml/) for Jupyter Hub, the `storage` part should look like the following:

```
...
    extraVolumes:
        - name: home
          hostPath:
            path: /data/homes/{username}
        - name: tutorial
          hostPath:
            path: /data/homes/_tutorials
        - name: my-config
          configMap:
            name: aviral-configmap
    extraVolumeMounts:
        - name: home
          mountPath: /home/jovyan
        - name: tutorial
          mountPath: /home/jovyan/tutorials
          readOnly: True
        - name: my-config
          mountPath: /home/jovyan/.ipython/profile_default/startup
...
```

Or another approach, you could modify your `config.yaml` and change `postStart` command so it might look like this:

```
...
postStart:
      exec:
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "test -d $HOME/my-work || mkdir $HOME/my-work; mkdir -p /home/jovyan/.ipython/profile_default/startup; echo 'run_id = sample' > aviral.py"]
...
```

You can check the documentation about [Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava, command `test` check if file exists and parameter `-d` checks if this file is a directory. I took this line from [https://jupyernetes.com/config-yaml/](https://jupyernetes.com/config-yaml/)

Comment: Also, as per your last approach, is this(https://pastebin.com/fYZQn34J) what you are proposing?

Comment: why would I need to check the file if I have to create a new one?
And if I need to check, why is this checking done on `my-work` than the actual directory: `/home/jovyan/.ipython/profile_default/startup`?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava, unfortunately I won't be able to help you regarding Jupyter Hub because I don't know it. I've posted answer from Kubernetes perspective.

Comment: hey, I am sorry but your last approach didn't work. 

My YAML is: https://pastebin.com/fYZQn34J

I checked and there was no new file creation.

Comment: @AviralSrivastava, the command should be in one line. Are you using helm to install Jupyter?

Comment: yes. I am using helm to install jupyter. It is successful without any error but when I check the file creation, it does not exist.

I have modified the command to `command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /home/jovyan/.ipython/profile_default/startup; echo run_id = \"sample\" ' > aviral.py"]`. Let's see.